# Outlook (.ics) TimeStamp ISO 8601 misinaptation

Tags: email, time, outlook, timezone, icalendar

I am sending .ics Datein vor this i use the time stamp in the ISO 8601 standert.

```
DTSTART:20161014T210013+2 DTEND:20161014T213013+2
```

and for google mail/calender this is totaly fine but outlook misjudge this as

```
Mo 01.01.1601 1:00 - 1:00
```

i can´t only send the time without an timezone information, because my software has to  runn on an server and hast to work in several different countries. So the timestamp wich i get from the user Input hast to contain that information.
has anyone an suggestion ?

Comment: there isn´t any solution You have to convert into UTC (GMT) vor Outlook, but then i can´t get gmail to display the corect time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert into UTC **and** add a 'Z' suffix to your datetime (e.g. 20161014T230013Z) so that the client that this is a date with UTC time. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5